# Are there online resourses that automatically translates English to classical Chinese?

Tags: translation, classical-chinese, resources, websites

Google translate supports traditional Chinese and simplified Chinese but not classical Chinese. On the other hand, classical Chinese is one of the supported languages of Wikipedia. Are there online resourses that automatically translates English to classical Chinese?

Comment: Not an answer, but related: http://kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eyasuoka/kyodokenkyu/2018-12-01.html - a recently developed Classical Chinese to English parser.

Comment: Thank you @droooze! It seems to be developed by a Japanese instead of Chinese. Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Baidu Translate](http://fanyi.baidu.com) does offer this functionality. Also seems that it is the only widely available service that can translate directly from English to Classical Chinese.

Good luck!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for sharing!!

Comment: Yes, for chinese searching and relative stuff, baidu is more powerful than google.